# What is the NIST/FIPS publication process? How long does it usually take for drafts to become final?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, compliance, fips, nist

I'm specifically concerned with EdDSA being made FIPS compliant, which I realize might take longer with the concerns raised with ECDSA, but I'm curious what the process actually is.

Is it all internal to NIST with just the Public Comment Period being the only transparency we get in the process?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, starting last June, all testing was to go through NIST's Automated Cryptographic Validation Protocol (ACVP).

An overview is available [here](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Automated-Cryptographic-Validation-Testing), and more information is published on [GitHub](https://usnistgov.github.io/ACVP/).

I think this provides some transparency into the process, though I'm not sure this is the kind of public/transparency you where asking about.

Cheers,